# Sitecore - How to search by field in multilist with search?

Tags: sitecore, sitecore7, sitecore7.2

I've made a field "Multilist with Search" in my solution. The point of this field is to add related articles to an article. I have set a source similar to this:

```
TemplateFilter={TemplateID}&StartSearchLocation=query:/path/to/list/of/items
```

I want make a search that finds a certain field value. For example, if I want to find the articleId on the searched article. Is there built-in support for this in Sitecore 7.2?

Is it possible to make a search like `articleID:706453`?

Comment: Have you tried entering '706453' directly in search box? Sitecore searches against 'content' lucene field which includes all fields values

Comment: That actually works! Guess I wasn't patient enough... Taught it would work with wildcard char. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I guess it's not the most easiest solution you're looking for, but you can extend IDataSource in your code and use the type as value in the Source-textbox for the field you want to use it for. With IDataSource you just return an array of items that will be use for your field. You can query whatever item you want.

See the article from John West on the Sitecore blog: http://www.sitecore.net/nederland/Community/Technical-Blogs/John-West-Sitecore-Blog/Posts/2013/09/Sitecore-7-Custom-Classes-as-Data-Template-Field-Sources.aspx

Otherwise you can try this:

StartSearchLocation=query:/path/to/list/of/items/*[@articleID = '123']

Note that Sitecore queries can be slow.